# How to Check the existence of multiple files in a directory and zip the same

Tags: shell-script

I am facing an issue while checking the existence of files ending with the same string/pattern. The file names might be as follows

```
abs_123.unl
xyz_123.unl
```

Currently my code is as below and working fine for single file, but in case there is multiple files available with the same pattern this if condition failing

```
if [ -s $AZWORK/*$PRCSID.unl ]
then
  tar -cvzf $WORK/INET_$PRCSID.unl.gz $WORK/*$PRCSID.unl
fi
```

here $PRCSID represents the last three digits in the file

How can I get this shell script to work for multiple files?

Comment: You should always quote shell variables (e.g., `"$AZWORK"`, `"$WORK"`, and `"$PRCSID"`) unless you have a good reason not to, and you’re *sure* you know what you’re doing.  Yes, as long as you know exactly what values the variables contain (and they don't include spaces or other special characters, like `*`), you don't *absolutely need* them.  But having them (the quotes) is like having insurance — they can save you from disaster when the unexpected happens.  … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … …  P.S. Did you mean to say `AZWORK` on the first line but then just `WORK` on the third line?

Answer (score 4):

I would delegate the "finding" and "sizing" of the files to `find`:

```
find "$WORK" -maxdepth 1 -name "*$PRCSID.unl" -type f  ! -size 0 -print0 | \
   xargs -0 --no-run-if-empty tar -cvzf "$WORK/INET_$PRCSID.unl.gz"
```

that way you can also filter out any subdirectories that might have the `"*_123.unl"` pattern.

Options for `find`:

- `-maxdepth 1` prevents recursion into subdirectories
- `-name "*$PRCSID.unl"` matches the filenames, make sure it is quoted to prevent `*` from being expanded by the shell.
- `-type f` only files
- `! -size 0` size does matter!
- `-print0` print the names NUL separated, not strictly necessary here, but it would be if the filenames have newlines in them, and it won't hurt

Options/parameters for `xargs`:

- `-0` assume stdin is NUL separated (instead of newline separated)
- `--no-run-if-empty` do not run if no data presented on stdin (i.e. find did have output)
- rest of the line is the command to run, with the data from stdin appended as parameters

Comment: I'm shocked to find myself telling *you* that shell variables (e.g., `"$WORK"` and `"$PRCSID"`) should always be quoted.

Comment: @Scott Thanks. Hope the feeling of horror doesn't last too long. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You could simply do:

```
tar -cvzf "$WORK/INET_$PRCSID.unl.gz" "$WORK"/*"$PRCSID.unl"
```

Comment: This will fail on file names with whitespace. There is absolutely no reason to use `ls`, just use shell globbing: `tar -cvzf "$WORK/INET_$PRCSID.unl.gz" "$WORK/*$PRCSID.unl"`

Comment: @terdon!  I was about to down-vote this answer, until I saw that he was just doing ***exactly what you suggested***.  Please don't tell me that I need to explain why your suggestion is wrong.

Comment: @Scott Ouch. No, you don't. Thanks for pointing it out, it's fixed now. UncleAlbie, sorry about that, the shell does not expand `*` inside quotes. You need to quote your variables to protect against whitespace, but the wildcard needs to be unquoted.

Comment: @terdon You're welcome.  Still no upvote from me, though, as this corrected version is just the third line from the OP's `if`-`then`-`fi` statement (plus appropriately placed quotes), and so does not address the issue of how to avoid running the `tar` command if there are no matching files.

Comment: @Scott as far as I can tell, that's not the question asked. The OP wants to know how to run this for _multiple_ files, not how to avoid running it for single ones.

Comment: @terdon As I [pointed out to @Anthon](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/212529/how-to-check-the-existence-of-multiple-files#comment360453_212678), the question says, "Currently my code is … working fine for [a] single file, but in case there [are] multiple files available with the same pattern this `if` condition [is] failing".  The OP has a `tar` command that works perfectly fine for multiple files (unless, of course, `$WORK` and/or `$PRCSID` contains space(s) or special character(s)), so why would he be asking for that?  "I am facing an issue *while checking the existence* of files …"

Answer (score 1):

To check for the existence of files matching a pattern,
you can do something like

```
if [ "$(shopt -s nullglob; printf "%s" "$WORK"/*"$PRCSID".unl)" != "" ]
then
    tar -cvzf "$WORK/INET_$PRCSID.unl.gz" "$WORK"/*"$PRCSID".unl
fi
```

<sup>(I’m assuming that you didn’t intend to look in one place for `.unl` files
and then archive files from another place.)</sup>

`shopt -s nullglob` causes filename patterns to “expand” to nothing
when they match nothing, so, if there are no files with names ending
with `123.unl` in the work directory,
the string argument `"$WORK"/*"$PRCSID".unl` vanishes,
leaving `printf` with nothing to print.

Notes:

- You can bring the `shopt -s nullglob` outside of the `if` statement, e.g.,

  ```
  shopt -s nullglob                        # Maybe elsewhere in the script
     ⋮
  if [ "$(printf "%s" "$WORK"/*"$PRCSID".unl)" != "" ]
  then
      tar -cvzf "$WORK/INET_$PRCSID.unl.gz" "$WORK"/*"$PRCSID".unl
  fi
  ```

  if you’re willing to have that behavior
  (the null expansion of non-matching patterns)
  in effect through the execution of the script.
- You should always quote shell variables (e.g., `"$WORK"` and `"$PRCSID"`)
  unless you have a good reason not to,
  and you’re *sure* you know what you’re doing. 
  You can do them piecemeal, quoting just the variables, e.g.,

  ```
  "$WORK"/*"$PRCSID".unl    and    "$WORK"/INET_"$PRCSID".unl.gz
  ```

  or you can quote entire words that contain variables, e.g.,

  ```
  "$WORK/"*"$PRCSID.unl"    and    "$WORK/INET_$PRCSID.unl.gz"
  ```

  but note that you must not do `"$WORK/*$PRCSID.unl"`,
  because that encloses the `*` in quotes, and thus prevents it from acting
  as a filename expansion pattern (i.e., wildcard or glob).
- Since your filename pattern begins
  with a directory name that you have some control over —
  especially if it’s a full path (beginning with `/`) or you can at least
  guarantee that it *doesn’t* begin with **`-`**) —
  then you’re probably safe using `echo` instead of `printf "%s"`; i.e.,

  ```
  if [ "$(shopt -s nullglob; echo "$WORK"/*"$PRCSID".unl)" != "" ]
  then
      tar -cvzf "$WORK/INET_$PRCSID.unl.gz" "$WORK"/*"$PRCSID".unl
  fi
  ```

  and of course you can pull the `shopt -s nullglob`
  out of the `if` statement here as well.

#### Another approach

If you *need* to have an `if`-`then`-`else` (or at least an `if`-`then`),
e.g., to write status/log/error messages, you should probably use the above. 
But, if your only concern is executing the `tar` command
only if there are file(s) there,
you can dispense with the `if`-`then` and just do

```
(shopt -s failglob; tar -cvzf "$WORK/INET_$PRCSID.unl.gz" "$WORK"/*"$PRCSID".unl)
```

`shopt -s failglob` means, if a command is attempted
with an argument containing filename pattern(s) that match nothing,
*the command is not executed*. 
The above precisely achieves the effect
that the code in your question is trying to achieve:
execute the `tar` command if there are files with names ending with `123.unl`
in the work directory, and don’t if there aren’t any.

Again, you can separate the `shopt -s failglob` from the `tar` command, e.g.,

```
shopt -s failglob                        # Maybe elsewhere in the script
   ⋮
tar -cvzf "$WORK/INET_$PRCSID.unl.gz" "$WORK"/*"$PRCSID".unl
```

if you’re willing to have that behavior (the non-execution of commands
with non-matching patterns) in effect through the execution of the script.

Comment: If `klm_123.unl` is a directory under `$WORK`, that gets included in the `tar.gz` as well as any and all files it might contain. The OP explicitly stated only to want "multiple files in a directory", which to me implies not wanting anything from other directories. This also backs up a a single empty file in `$WORK` which the OP's test on `-s` would have skipped.

Comment: Good points.  In fact, the second one had occurred to me, and I intended to mention it, but, in the course of typing up *War and Peace* :-) , it slipped my mind.  As to the first one, the question says, "Currently my code is ... working fine for [a] single file, but in case there [are] multiple files available with the same pattern this `if` condition [is] failing", and the OP's current code will also fail if there is a `foo_123.unl` directory.  Indeed, yours seems to be the only answer that distinguishes between `file_123.unl` and `dir_123.unl`.

Comment: With hindsight I think the post should have been closed as "unclear what you are asking" to force the OP to provide a better picture of what was exactly wanted.  The question is sloppy at best (look at the edit history) Originally I thought about answering with a for loop testing each matching file and setting  a variable if any of the files was non-zero and then run the tar. But my bash skills are limited (as you noticed) so I did not follow that way . (And I did not want to answer using python circumventing any quoting problems).

Comment: Answering here so we don't spam poor UncleAlbie. Fair enough, the OP is using `[ -s ]` so presumably they want to avoid running when no files are found. Still think it would be easier to just run `tar -cvzf "$WORK/INET_$PRCSID.unl.gz" "$WORK"/*"$PRCSID.unl" || rm "$WORK/INET_$PRCSID.unl.gz"` though. Less clean granted :)

Answer (score -1):

`find` command can find the required files for you and then execute any command on the result like this:

```
find $WORK -name *.unl -exec tar -zcvf $WORK/INET_$PRCSID.unl.gz {} \;
```

Comment: That will just overwrite the archive with each file found. You will only have the last one in the archive.  `+` instead of `\;` would be better but, again, there's no guarantee that all the files will go into the archive. It will fail if there are too many files.

Comment: In addition to @terdon's criticism, (1) You should always quote shell variables (e.g., `"$WORK"` and `"$PRCSID"`) unless you have a good reason not to, and you’re *sure* you know what you’re doing, and (2) you should always quote wildcards (a.k.a. globs or filename expansion patterns; i.e., strings containing `*`, `?`, and/or `[…]`), such as `"*.unl"`, when you want them to be interpreted *by the program that you're passing them to* rather than the shell.  `find  …  -name ` *`pattern `* `…` is the best known example of that (also `-path` and `-regex`, of course).